# How do I associate icons to zip file type with an iPhone/iPad application?

Tags: iphone

Here is my code in plist file.
It run correctly but the icon was not displayed.

```
<key>CFBundleDocumentTypes</key>
<array>
    <dict>
        <key>CFBundleTypeIconFiles</key>
        <array>
            <string>iPad-320.png</string>
            <string>iPad-64.png</string>
        </array>
        <key>CFBundleTypeName</key>
        <string>Zip Archive</string>
        <key>CFBundleTypeRole</key>
        <string>Editor</string>
        <key>LSHandlerRank</key>
        <string>Owner</string>
        <key>LSItemContentTypes</key>
        <array>
            <string>com.pkware.zip-archive</string>
        </array>
    </dict>
</array>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use  `CFBundleIconFiles` like this:

```
<key>CFBundleIconFiles</key>
<array>
    <string>icon.png</string>
    <string>icon@2x.png</string>
    <string>icon-72.png</string>
</array>
```